# When working with spring MVC there is a 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

When working with spring MVC there is a 404 error. Can anyone help me please. Where is the mistake in my project? There are no errors when starting the server.

Tomcat version 10.1.11
Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.3.3

[here is all my project](https://github.com/MaksKroha/SpringMVC.git)

Thank you.

I thought that the controller could not find the index.jsp file, but it turned out that this is not the problem. Maybe the file controller is not executed at all

Comment: Show the URL you're hitting. Presumably it's <yourhost:port/context-root>/hello ? Also, Spring MVC startup logging will log all URLs that are bound if you have DEBUG logging level enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my URL pattern: instead of `/*` I should only use `/`